# Stop timer using promise in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this start timer function

```
async startTimer() {
    this.count = 30;
    for (var i = 30; i >= 0; i--) {
      await new Promise((f) => setTimeout(f, 1000));
      this.count = i;
    }
  }
```

which gets started by calling `this.startTimer()` but when i try to set `this.count=0` to stop the timer it doesn't stop rather than when i run `this.startTimer` again old one also run.

Any solution please. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What happens after you set `this.count = 0`?
`startTimer` waits for promise, then it sets `this.count = i`, then it does `i--`, then it checks condition `i >= 0`, so the loop simply continues. There is nothing that breaks the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `i`, use `count` directly instead. Also introduce a `isRunning` flag.

Following example still leverages to -1, since you can't cancel a promise.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  count: number = 0;
  isRunning: boolean = false;

  async startTimer() {
    if (!this.isRunning) {
      this.isRunning = true;
      for (this.count = 30; this.count >= 0 && this.isRunning; this.count--) {
        await new Promise((f) => setTimeout(f, 1000));
      }
      this.isRunning = false;
    }
  }

  stopTimer() {
    this.isRunning = false;
  }
}
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p4zg94?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thanks so using async function after timer is started it cannot be stopped as we generally do `clearInterval`, i'm not clear with async function here how it is used, can you pls explain